# Restarting the network with composer.sh causes connection error when using again?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I installed the latest Composer locally on an Ubantu Linux and then started with the `composer.sh`. It works fine, I can do anything what I want. After restarting the composer, however, it fails to connect again.

I get the following error:

> Exception:
>   Error: Error trying to ping.
>   Error: make sure the chaincode gowdanar-funds has been successfully instantiated and try again: getccdata composerchannel/gowdanar-funds responded with error: could not find chaincode with name 'gowdanar-funds'
>   Error: Error trying to ping.
>   Error: make sure the chaincode gowdanar-funds has been successfully instantiated and try again: getccdata composerchannel/gowdanar-funds responded with error: could not find chaincode with name 'gowdanar-funds'
>       at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:798:34)
>       at anonymous

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to vertion problem of your node js. Check the node vertion by typing node -v comment. The change the vertion of node js to 8.11.3 or 8.9. Then restart it.

Comment: sir after changing the node js version to 8.9 facing the same issue                         Error: Error trying to ping. Error: make sure the chaincode gowdanar-funds has been successfully instantiated and try again: getccdata composerchannel/gowdanar-funds responded with error: could not find chaincode with name 'gowdanar-funds'
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: make sure the chaincode gowdanar-funds has been successfully instantiated and try again: getccdata composerchannel/gowdanar-funds responded with error: could not find chaincode with name 'gowdanar-funds'

Comment: Please share the link of your git file. And share the composer vertion.